# Asus, Ubuntu 20.04 NVIDIA graphics drivers

Tags: nvidia, asus

After I installed ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus Q550L laptop the computer was having problems with a pink screen. I tried to download a new NVIDIA graphics driver and now I have a completely black screen. Please help

Comment: 1. Don't install Nvidia drivers from the Nvidia binaries, they're already available at the Ubuntu repository and **automatically installed when the correct option is ticked during Ubuntu installation**. If not they can be installed later by accessing Additional Drivers, NEVER from the Nvidia website. 2. Regardless of the method you need to either disable Secure Boot in UEFI or use mokutil to sign the drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu repository has it's own drivers that are more compatible to your device and I recommend you to use the Ubuntu ones,

If you are directed to a shell after login simply run this command to install the drivers:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If you're not directed then go to the **Advanced Options > recovery mode > Drop to root shell prompt** path after boot and run the command